# Scala reduceByKey function - use any type that has + method

Tags: scala

I am writing a simple function called `reduceByKey` that takes a collection of (key, numeric) pairs and returns reduced collection by key.

```
  def reduceByKey[K](collection: Traversable[Tuple2[K, Int]]) = {    
    collection
      .groupBy(_._1)
      .map { case (group: K, traversable) => traversable.reduce{(a,b) => (a._1, a._2 + b._2)} }
  }
```

This currently works for:

```
scala> val col = List((("some","key"),100), (("some","key"),100), (("some","other","key"),50))
col: List[(Product with Serializable, Int)] = List(((some,key),100), ((some,key),100), ((some,other,key),50))

scala>  reduceByKey(col)      
res42: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Product with Serializable,Int] = Map((some,key) -> 200, (some,other,key) -> 50)
```

But, I as soon as I want to use non-Int type for numeric, it fails miserably, as it expects an `Int`.

```
scala> val col = List((("some","key"),100.toDouble), (("some","key"),100.toDouble), (("some","other","key"),50.toDouble))
col: List[(Product with Serializable, Double)] = List(((some,key),100.0), ((some,key),100.0), ((some,other,key),50.0))

scala> reduceByKey(col)
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[(Product with Serializable, Double)]
 required: Traversable[(?, Int)]
              reduceByKey(col)
                                ^
```

Of course, I could make different methods for different types, but that would be silly. Basically I want my method to work with any type that has `+` method defined. That would be `Double`, `Float`, `Long`, `Int` and `Short`.

1. At first, I thought I could use structural type instead of Int. But that would mean the structural type would need to reference itself in order to be of any use.
2. I looked into [Numeric](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.2/scala/math/Numeric.html) trait that I think could be useful. It encapsulates the + methods of all numeric types. However, I am not sure how to use it in my case. I dont want force the user of my function to wrap values in Numeric just for my function to work. The function itself should somehow implicitly wrap it up and invoke `Numeric.plus`.

I am open to any suggestions as how to solve this.

Comment: It's an answer, but so terse as not to deserve being put forth as such: Use a typeclass. Someone else will give the details soon enough, probably. If not, I'll try to make the time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are only interested in numeric values, you can use the standard `Numeric` type class and do this:

```
def reduceByKey[K,V](collection: Traversable[Tuple2[K, V]])(implicit num: Numeric[V]) = {    
  import num._
  collection
    .groupBy(_._1)
    .map { case (group: K, traversable) => traversable.reduce{(a,b) => (a._1, a._2 + b._2)} }
}
```

The `num` implicit parameter serves as an evidence that `V` is a numeric type, and provides the `+` operation for this type.